# Work permit in Poland without returning to Canada

Tags: eu, poland, working-visas

If I want to apply for a work permit to Poland, do I have to come back to Canada and submit my documents to the closest consulate, or can this be done within the EU, where I presently temporarily reside as a Canadian visitor (not in Poland presently)?

Comment: @Traveller Yes, but will I have to go back to Canada to submit all the relevant documents, including the employment offer, to the Polish consulate, or can such be done in any other country where I temporarily reside?

Comment: In the EU, whether you can apply for a residence permit in the country typically depends on how you entered the country in the first place, as well as on your citizenship.  The place where you must apply outside the country, if you are doing so, depends on your place of residence.  The details are different from one EU country to the next, but at least in this case we know that the country is Poland.  We can assume that you are either a resident or citizen of Canada; are you both?  Did you enter the Schengen area without a visa, that is, as a short-term visitor?

Comment: @phoog All answers are yes.